# how to find radius of convergence of a series of unconventional powers like this?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

$S = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+7\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)2^n}z^{2n-1}$

if it were $ z ^ n $ I would use

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a^n}|$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |{a_n}|^\frac{1}{n}$

how to work with that $ 2n-1 $ ??
the template is $ | z | < \sqrt {2} $

Answer (score 1):

We will treat it as a numerical series $\sum u_n (z) $.

the ratio test gives the limit

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac {u_{n+1}(z)}{u_n(z)}=\frac {z^2}{2} $$

thus if $|z|<\sqrt {2} $, it converges and if $|z|>\sqrt {2} $  , it diverges.

$\sqrt {2} $ is the Radius of convergence.

Comment: is not understood, for me this result, so it is worth if for $ z ^ n $, and how this limit gave $ z² / 2 $ ????

Comment: @Joewandellie Observe that $u_n (z)\sim \frac {z^{2n-1}}{2^n} $.

Comment: And what did you do with the rest? I found that we calculated the radius of convergence using the $ a_n $ of the summation term $ a_n \cdot (z-a)^n $